# create site map in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, sitemap

i want create site map in yii2
I do not know what I would do.
Help me Where do I start?
this is my news model :

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'news';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['news_cat_id', 'user_id','time'], 'integer'],
        [['news_dec'], 'string'],
        [['news_title', 'logo'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

i cant work with extension because that haven't good document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install package `composer require evert/sitemap-php`
2. Create command Controller for console app in @app/commands/ directory.

   class SitemapController extends Controller
   {

   ```
   public function actionIndex(){

       $host = 'http://yoursitehost.com/';

       $sitemap = new Sitemap($host);

       $sitemap->setPath(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

       $sitemap->addItem('', '1.0', 'daily', 'Today');
       $sitemap->addItem('news', '9.0', 'daily', 'Today');

       foreach(News::find()->batch(50) as $news){
           foreach($news as $n){
               $sitemap->addItem(Url::toRoute(['news/view', 'id' => $n->id]), '8.0', 'daily', 'Today');
           }
       }

       $sitemap->createSitemapIndex($host, 'Today');
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add your controller to console.php config file.

   $config = [
       ...
       'controllerMap' => [
           'sitemap' => [
               'class' => 'app\commands\SitemapController'
           ],
       ]
   ];

And add to top console.php `Yii::setAlias('@webroot', dirname(__DIR__) . '/../web');`

4. Run command `php yii sitemap`. Script generate file sitemap.xml to web directory.
5. Go to link - http://yourhost.com/sitemap.xml.

You can run this command `php yii sitemap` by cron.

Comment: i do inistalled with composer.
but Where do I enter the sample code?

Comment: you can create an action in the controller and generate a sitemap there

Comment: XMLWriter::openUri(): Unable to resolve file path

for this :     $sitemap->addItem('/', '1.0', 'daily', 'Today');

Comment: add to top console.php Yii::setAlias('@webroot', dirname(__DIR__) . '/../web');

Comment: try this $sitemap->addItem('', '1.0', 'daily', 'Today'); without slash

Comment: have error for this in else :
 if ($this->getCurrentSitemap()) {
            $this->getWriter()->openURI($this->getPath() . $this->getFilename() . self::SEPERATOR . $this->getCurrentSitemap() . self::EXT);
        } else {
            $this->getWriter()->openURI($this->getPath() . $this->getFilename() . self::EXT);
        }

Comment: Please send your code me to email vitgvr@gmail.com, i try in my local pc

Comment: Operation system Unix or Windows ?

Comment: I have not time now to work on this part of the project.